# gcc why does -Woverflow not catch int8_t i = 128;?

Tags: gcc

edit: it's probably a gcc bug. reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108798

int8_t has a range of -128 to 127, so when compiling the code

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main(){
    int8_t i = 128;
    (void)i;
}
```

with

```
gcc t.c -Woverflow
```

why does it not catch the 128 overflow? fwiw gcc catches the overflow only when you go over 255, for example

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main(){
    int8_t i = 256;
    (void)i;
}
```

is caught. so why isn't 128 caught?

interestingly, it catches the 128 overflow with `-Woverflow -Wpedantic` , resulting in a

```
prog.c:3:15: warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'int8_t' {aka 'signed char'} changes value from '128' to '-128' [-Woverflow]
    3 |     int8_t ii=128;
```

tested with gcc 12.1.0 (released 2022-05-06)

Comment: The warning is also disabled if you subsequently pass `-Wno-overflow` OR `-Wno-pedantic`. The behavior seems consistent with having an implicit `-Wno-pedantic` preceding the warning options - perhaps that is how gcc is treating this internally?